# Azure Key Vault security (Admin Question)

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I work at an organization that uses Azure and I need to set up an ETL process that will pull data from an API. Based on my research, everywhere on the internet says I should use Azure Key Vault to store the credentials rather than hard code them into Data Factory. I created a "secret" within a key vault that I created and configured the settings to only grant access to my windows login. However, my Azure subscription is part of an enterprise/multi-tenant subscription and I had a colleague (who has never used Azure before) screen-share with me, and he was able to access the credentials in the key vault I created simply by changing the access settings to "public" (he is able to see them in plain text after modifying the Network/Security settings).

Is this the expected behavior? I can see the benefit of allowing other user to modify the setting for a Key Vault (if I leave the company for example), but I'm not sure if there is a way around this, because I would assume if my co-worker (who is not admin-level) can see these credentials, than the IT department and/or higher-ranking people would be able to access these credentials quite easily...

Pretty much everything I find online says I should store credentials in Azure Key Vault, but if my whole organization has the ability to access the secrets, doesn't that seem like a major security issue?

**Access Policy settings** - Application is an Azure Data Factory instance which I created, User is my login/account
[image]

**Networking settings** - Private endpoint option is selected, but currently no private endpoints are on the access list. Co-worker was able to change this to "All networks", ultimately granting him access to view secrets.
[image]

Comment: Could you share some information/screenshots of the settings your colleague changed to get access to the Keyvault? If he was able to do this via the Azure portal, it seems that your Enterprise  may have given Azure access to all the folks.  You can check this by clicking the IAM and/or Access policies tab on the left. Whatever you heard and read online about Keyvault is true. Secrets can be viewed in plain text but only by those who are allowed to do so. Also have a read of this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague is probably having Owner or Contibutor role on subscription level. So he can change Key Vault settings and grant access to himself. This behaviour is by design.
It is explained in [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/security-features#management-plane-and-rbac) about Key Vault security:

*If a user has Contributor permissions to a key vault management plane, the user can grant themselves access to the data plane by setting a Key Vault access policy. You should tightly control who has Contributor role access to your key vaults. Ensure that only authorized persons can access and manage your key vaults, keys, secrets, and certificates.*